# colab not employing css

Tags: css, google-colaboratory

When running jupyter on my own machine, the code below (first cell) affects all subsequent cells that reference the css rule, i.e., it works as expected. When I run it in colab, it has no effect. Is there an equivalent form that will work with both local and colab jupyter environments?

```
%%html
<style>
.h1_cell {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", "Georgia", "Serif";
    font-size: 125%;
    line-height: 22px; /* 5px +12px + 5px */
    text-indent: 15px;
    background-color: #fbfbea; //#e6e6e6;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Subsequent markdown cells have a header of

```
<div class=h1_cell>
```

Answer (score 2):

Each Colab output is rendered in a distinct iframe sandbox. So, any style changes will only apply to the output of the cell where the customization is executed.

Comment: I copied the code and the style changes does not apply to the output of the cell where the customization is executed.

Comment: Please ask a distinct question for a distinct issue. And, please do include a self-contained notebook that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I don't understand /:-|  Now everything works well+1. When I investigated what you said I worked on at the same time two other colab notebooks. This is not the first case that "too much" opened notebook maybe disturb each other. Sorry.